# Typeof undefined when trying to access property of object nested in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I've got an array that holds a mix of objects and arrays that contain objects with the same properties

```
plantsArray = [
{type: "wheat", height: 20, output: 25},
{type: "soybeans", height: 30, output: 29},
[{type: "corn", height: 34, output: 9}, {type: "wheat", height: 20, output: 25}],
{type: "wheat", height: 20, output: 25}, 
..etc
]
```

Trying to take each individual object, look up the value of "output" and push that many more objects into a new array:

```
const harvestOutput = []

for (const plantItem of plantsArray) {

        if (Array.isArray(plantItem) ) {
                for (let i = 0; i < plantItem[i].output; i++) {
                    harvestOutput.push(plantItem[i])
            }
        } 
        else

        for(let k = 0; k < plantItem.output; k++) {
            harvestOutput.push(plantItem)
        }
    }
```

And getting error "cannot read property "output" of undefined" for that `plantObj[i]` reference... without suggesting others methods and solutions and such please and thanks (I know they're out there, this a school exercise!), am I missing something in either the syntax or the logic for **accessing the value of the "output" property of those nested objects**? The way I'm reading this, starting at the if statement, is "If plantItem is an array, set a variable i to 0, and as long as i is less than the value of the "output" property of the entry found at index position i of plantItem ...etc".

Rest of it executes fine.

Thanks!

**EDIT plantObj was a typo, fixed **

Comment: You have not defined plantObj anywhere, let me know what you are trying to achieve, I can help you with the code

Answer (score 1):

In the first for you need a for to loop through your array then another one to loop through output. In your second for you push plantObj wich doesn't exist.

```js
plantsArray = [
  {type: "wheat", height: 20, output: 25},
  {type: "soybeans", height: 30, output: 29},
  [{type: "corn", height: 34, output: 9}, {type: "wheat", height: 20, output: 25}],
  {type: "wheat", height: 20, output: 25}
]

const harvestOutput = [];

for (const plantItem of plantsArray) {
    if (Array.isArray(plantItem) ) {
        for (let i = 0; i < plantItem.length; i++)
          for (let j = 0; j <= plantItem[i].output; j++) {
            harvestOutput.push({...plantItem[i]}); // the {...} is to destructuring the object and make a copy
          }
    } 
    else
      for (let j = 0; j <= plantItem.output; j++) {
        harvestOutput.push({...plantItem});
      }
}

console.log(harvestOutput);
```

Comment: He wants to iterate it 25 times if output is 25.

Answer (score 1):

You can flat array and then map

```js
let plantsArray = [
{type: "wheat", height: 20, output: 25},
{type: "soybeans", height: 30, output: 29},
[{type: "corn", height: 34, output: 9}, {type: "wheat", height: 20, output: 25}],
{type: "wheat", height: 20, output: 25}];


let result = plantsArray.flat(1).map(x => x.output);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: He said he don't want a way to do it but why his way doesn't work.

Comment: flat() is a good resourse to access nested array and i think is helpfull to be aware of that

Answer (score 1):

You have missed nested array looping. And instead of plantItem you have used as plantObj. I have added as the comment in the respective place.

```js
const plantsArray = [{
        type: "wheat",
        height: 20,
        output: 25
    },
    {
        type: "soybeans",
        height: 30,
        output: 29
    },
    [{
        type: "corn",
        height: 34,
        output: 9
    }, {
        type: "wheat",
        height: 20,
        output: 25
    }],
    {
        type: "wheat",
        height: 20,
        output: 25
    }
]

const harvestOutput = []

for (const plantItem of plantsArray) {
    if (Array.isArray(plantItem)) {
        //You have missed this looping 
        for (let i = 0; i < plantItem.length; i++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < plantItem[i].output; k++) {
                harvestOutput.push(plantItem[i])
            }
        }
    } else
        //Instead of plantItem you have used plantObj here so it is undefined.
        for (let k = 0; k < plantItem.output; k++) {
            harvestOutput.push(plantItem)
        }
}

console.log(harvestOutput);
```

Moreover I would to give a suggestion,
You could move the following code part to a separate function to avoid code repetition.

```
 for (let k = 0; k < plantItem[i].output; k++) {
     harvestOutput.push(plantItem[i])
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will solve your problem ;)

```js
const plantsArray = [
    { type: 'wheat', height: 20, output: 25 },
    { type: 'soybeans', height: 30, output: 29 },
    [{ type: 'corn', height: 34, output: 9 }, { type: 'wheat', height: 20, output: 25 }],
    { type: 'wheat', height: 20, output: 25 }
];

let harvestOutput = [];
plantsArray.flat(1).forEach(plantItem => {
    const harvestedItems = new Array(plantItem.output).fill(plantItem);
    harvestOutput = harvestOutput.concat(harvestedItems);
});

console.log(harvestOutput);
```